# Keycloak with SAML as Identity Provider and LDAP User Federation

Tags: ldap, keycloak, saml

We use keycloak 9.0.3 and connect it to an SAML IdentityProvider. We want to use LDAP for UserFederation but not for Authentication, because Authentication is made by smartcard. But we want to access additional LDAP information e.g. groups. Is it possible to disable LDAP authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
Under "Authentication" on the "Flows" Tab select "Browser" in the drop down.
Then set "Identity Provider Redirector" to disabled.